# Python Rain meter, correct false positives

Tags: python

I have the following script running on a Pi Zero with a tipping bucket rain meter attached. As you can see it counts the number of tips, and logs to sql once every 30minutes. I have some false positives though. About 1 or 2 every 30 minutes. Every day, even the bone dry days. How can i avoid them? I was thinking something in the line of:

```
if rainTick <= 2:
     rainTick = 0
```

But i don't want it to reset the entire day, only the last 30 minutes. It should only reset completely at midnight.

```
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import mysql.connector

rainTick = 0
Input_Sig = 6
starttime = time.time()
last_day = datetime.datetime.now().day
lastrainevent = datetime.datetime.now()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(Input_Sig, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(Input_Sig, GPIO.FALLING,  bouncetime=5)

def raintrig(self):
    global rainTick
    rainTick += 1
 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='pi',
    passwd='************',
    database='weatherDB'
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

def write2DB(values):
    sqlText = '''INSERT INTO rainfall(rain) VALUES({:.2f})'''.format(values)
    #print( values, 'mm')
    mycursor.execute(sqlText)
    mydb.commit()

GPIO.add_event_callback(Input_Sig, raintrig)

while True:
 
    rainFall = rainTick * 0.2794
    day = datetime.datetime.now().day
    if day != last_day:
        last_day = day
        rainTick = 0
    print(rainFall, 'mm')
    write2DB(rainFall)
    time.sleep(1800.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

Comment: Could you tel if this code is run every 30 minutes ? or how you count time inside it? You may need to add another counter like 30minraintrig.

Comment: time.sleep(1800.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I may have it sorted. At least a very basic method of doing it.

```
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import mysql.connector

rainTick = 0
lastTick = 0
inputPin = 6
startTime = time.time()
lastDay = datetime.datetime.now().day

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(inputPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(inputPin, GPIO.FALLING,  bouncetime=5)

def rainTrig(self):
    global rainTick
    global lastTick
    rainTick += 1
    lastTick += 1
    
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='pi',
    passwd='Snabela1',
    database='weatherDB'
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

def write2DB(values):
    sqlText = '''INSERT INTO rainfall(rain) VALUES({:.2f})'''.format(values)
    mycursor.execute(sqlText)
    mydb.commit()

GPIO.add_event_callback(inputPin, rainTrig)

while True:
 
    if lastTick <= 2:
        rainTick -= lastTick   
    rainFall = rainTick * 0.2794
    day = datetime.datetime.now().day
    if day != lastDay:
        lastDay = day
        rainTick = 0
    lastTick = 0
    #print(rainFall, 'mm')
    write2DB(rainFall)
    time.sleep(1800.0 - ((time.time() - startTime) % 60.0))
```

I set up a new variable that resets every time, and if it equals either 1 or 2, it subtracts that vlue from the total.

Comment: Good. In def rainTrig(self): Your lastTick variable should be global like rainTick I suppose. ANd you can do:  if lastTick <= 2: rainTick-= lastTick

Comment: I already added the global, as I noticed something was wrong.

Comment: ok good, just edit it in your question so other people will see. Do you still have a question ? or just select your own answer.

Comment: Will do, and i can answer it in 18 hours.